# How to Disable col-sm and col-xs in bootstrap 3.

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am creating a template in bootstrap 3. Before I was plan to make it responsive for all device but now changed mind. 
Template is already complete.

I have used col-md in each row. 
Now I want that if page with goes less than 1100px page should scroll-x. 
I want to disable complete col-sm and col-xs,

I have already remove meta.

But still when page width come to small screen than 1100px it break to col-sm and then col-xs. 
I want minimum width of page 1100px. No what on what device its browsing.

Thank you

Comment: I did not want to create new bootstrap. I just want to disable col-sm and col-xs. I do not want my web page go to smaller screen than col-md,

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Bootstrap CSS and change the media query breakpoints to your liking.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

- the negative, not being able to link a CDN.
- the positive, not writing extra code.

Comment: I did not want to create new bootstrap. I just want to disable col-sm and col-xs. I do not want my web page go to smaller screen than col-md,

Comment: you will have to over-ride with CSS. the common way to deal with it, is generate your own bootstrap.css file using the above link. this will save you the hack-n-slash you will bump into later, if trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a local copy of boostrap in your web, one way is modify the width of the media query that control the size where col-md starts, for example:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
....
}
```

This is a fast way to do it, anyway is better to customice your own boostrap.

Comment: I did not want to create new bootstrap. I just want to disable col-sm and col-xs. I do not want my web page go to smaller screen than col-md,